# Apache mod_rewrite choose .png if .gif doesn't exist

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to change some gif files in my project to png images but not all of them, and I cant update all the zillions of paths in the project to point to png.

I want to remove the specific gifs from the projects imagefolder and replace with png. I then want to use mod_rewrite to get the png version of a file when the gif (which I will manually remove) doesnt exist.

This is what I have thought of so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "\.gif$"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule (.*)\.gif $1.png
```

Unfortunately this breaks all my images. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does it help if you change the second line to `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f`

Comment: no, unfortunately not

Comment: does it break all images or only the .pngs don't work as expected?

Comment: it breaks all images, i think there is something wrong with the second line

Comment: What is the Apache version?

Comment: The Apache Version is 2.4